# Multiple update notifications from Android Market

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, notifications, accounts

I have recently upgraded my HTC Desire to run CyanogenMod 7.  The main reason I did this was so that I could use a more recent version of the Android Market that supported multiple accounts.  The reason for this was that I have moved my email address from GMail to Google Apps for Your Domain and wanted the main email address on the phone to be the Google Apps one, but the market to keep using the gmail one so that I don't have to buy apps again.

I also have two other gmail/apps accounts configured on the phone (so that I can receive emails sent to these two accounts).

Generally, everything works fine and I'm really happy with CyanogenMod.  However, I have one fairly minor problem with the market.  When new updates are available to the installed apps, I used to get a notification message saying (e.g.)

```
2 New Updates are available
```

(I'm paraphrasing as no updates are currently available, so I can't remember the exact wording of the message).  This is quite instructive.  With the new market, I get FOUR notification messages:

```
2 New Updates are available email@mydomain.com

2 New Updates are available other_email@mydomain.com

2 New Updates are available more_email@gmail.com

2 New Updates are available email@gmail.com
```

This seems a bit daft as they're all the same updates!  Is there any way to sort this out?  The market is set up to use the email@gmail.com account, but seems to be checking for all of the accounts.  I'd imagine that if there are paid apps that need updating, they'll only be listed for the last account (although that's a guess), but for all the free ones I seem to be stuck with multiple messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is by design as the majority of users don't have 4 accounts on their phone. The whole idea of those messages is to give the user the opportunity to download a new version as soon as it comes out. You may not want to use your mobile data when you don't want it to. Maybe the update automatically tickbox would bypass this message, however it will probably still say that 3 updates have been applied.

So what you maybe looking for is silent updates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328471/can-we-do-silent-updation-for-android-application looks like you can do it with a rooted phone.

I too think that Google can handle multiple accounts in a more intuitive ways across their products. Since its out of our control to improve these closed source apps ourselves I will say its better than it used to be. I think the best solution for Google would be to combine these messages into one notification ie "5 apps have been updated".

Make some noise on the Google support pages to improve this UX, this may be a good start http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/label?lid=551c5c4cca827a18&hl=en