# Remove google accounts from Android Market

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, accounts

I have 2 accounts synced with the device, lets call them *Account A* and *Account B*.

When I got the device, I first entered A to be the account for the market, for gmail and everything else.
Then, I added B and selected "Sync with Google Calendar" **only**.

Lately, I've started getting notifications about application updates for B, and when I go to the market each time I have to make sure I selected A (And I **did** pick A in the market settings).

Can I **delete** B from the market? I don't want it to exist in that list when you select "Accounts" in the menu.

(Market version 3.3.11)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple update notifications from Android Market](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15523/multiple-update-notifications-from-android-market)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, probably only way to block it would be deleting it :(

Comment: But I'm still using it for the Google Calendar :/ There must be a way to add an account just for a specific purpose? (**not** the Market)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's definitely a bug, it's been raised on the [support forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=08abbd0b75013451&hl=en). 
There is a message from Google saying they're working on a fix.

Personally I'd really like to see "Market" as an option in the sync screen, just like Gmail, Calendar, Contacts etc... so we can just turn it off.

I recommend you go vote on the issue to give it more visibility.

Answer (score -2):

What you describe is a bug in the later versions of the Android Market. I believe it has been acknowledged by Google, and they are working on a solution.

Yes, you can delete the second account. You can normally remove any Google account expect for the FIRST one you added. However, you have to remove it completely, not just from the market. So, you will lose access to calendar and contacts etc.

From the homes screen, press "menu", then go to:

Settings -> Accounts & sync

Choose the account you want to remove, and then choose "Remove Account"

Comment: OP already stated in comment to @maxorq's answer that they don't want to delete account as they use it for Google Calendar.